# A function that doesn't block the loop from continuing

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to programming sorry, but I have a socket program that I aim to eventually be a chat room, however, the input functions stop my "send_message" loop in its tracks and can't continue until (obviously) until someone uses it.

This is the part I am refering too.

```py
def send_messages():
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter a message: ")
        response = send_message(user_input)
        print(f"Users Response: {response}")
        if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        threading.Thread(target=send_message, args=(user_input,)).start()
```

This part in particular

```py
response = send_message(user_input)
print(f"Users Response: {response}")
```

If i remove these, i can send multiple messages, however the client can not see the servers response. How can I fix this? I feel stuck. I am using threads by the way if that adds to your answer.

Comment: allow the loop to continue while waiting for user input you can use threads to handle user input separately from the message sending process

Comment: by using two separate threads one for sending messages and another for receiving user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, the answer is in `threading`. But launching a thread to send data is not really useful — the delay is not in sending, and your thread is very short-lived. Instead, you can have two loops running in parallel, each in its own thread:

- a receiver thread, which waits for data from socket and prints what it receives, and
- a sender thread, which waits for input from user and sends what it gets.

Alternately, you can divide it differently, though it is not as efficient:

- an UI thread, which takes input from user and shoves it into a `Queue`
- a communication thread, which checks the queue and sends the contents if it is not empty, then reads from socket (with timeout) and prints what it finds there.